# How to activate virtual environment remotely on Pycharm?

Tags: server, pycharm, virtualenv, portforwarding

I'm now working on projects that port forwarding to a remote server on Pycharm. Everything is fine, except that I can't activate available virtual environments from my remote server. It just has the option to create new ones, not activate the currently available env. I hope that someone could help me with this!

Comment: Could you please explain the setup in more detail? Do you have a remote interpreter over SSH configured in PyCharm? What do you mean by "It just has the option to create new ones"?

Comment: Yes, sure. What I meant by "It just has the option to create new ones" is the Pycharm just allows me to create a new virtual environment, instead of using my existing one. So I just wanna ask about how I can activate my existing virtual env here?